# How to adjust p-values and do post-hoc tests in glmmTMB models

Tags: mixed-model, glmmtmb

I am running a [glmmTBM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/glmmTMB.pdf) model with repeated measures from a group of participants with 5 factors, one covariate and I have interaction between factors.

I would like to ask what would be the best way to correct the obtained p-values  and what posthoc test I could run with a glmmTMB model.

My data are not Gaussian distributed and I need to consider participants as a random effect. For this reason I am using a glmmTBM model with the beta family and logit as the link function (the mixed effect version of a beta-regression model).

I am aware that usually, you can use Bonferroni or posthoc test like Tukey test, but in my case, the tests are not independent, so I am not sure which is the best way to proceed.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I am not sure how to get the p-values out of `glmmTMB` or even how to do post-hoc test, but if you know how to do it, the answer is simple, use the Bonferroni-Holm correction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method
It is uniformly more powerful than Bonferroni and very simple to compute.